# In general, what is feasible quantum computation?

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, quantum-operation, matrix-representation, hadamard

I don't really understand what is feasible quantum computation, in my book (Lipton and Regan's ***Quantum Algorithms via Linear Algebra***) they said that:

> A quantum computation $C$ on s qubits is feasible provided: $C=U_t.U_{t-1}…U_1$ where each $U_i$ is a feasible operation, and $s$ and $t$ are bounded by a polynomial in the designated number $n$ of input qubits.

What is a feasible operation? And is Hadamard matrix a feasible computation? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that each 'feasible operation' is meant to refer to a specific [quantum gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_logic_gate) that can be easily implemented on your particular quantum computer of interest, e.g. with one or a couple of laser pulses/microwave pulses/half-silvered mirrors/etc.

A gate-based quantum computer will operate with a particular set of basic primitive logic gates.  Depending on the technology, these primitive gates (or 'feasible operations') may include things like Hadamard gates and/or controlled-Z gates and/or square-root-of-SWAP gates, etc.

As long as the set of such primitives are computationally 'universal', then we can efficiently move from one set of universal gates to another set of universal gates (at up to a polynomial cost).  It is probably in this sense that the authors mean that each $U_i$ is 'feasible'.

A single-qubit Hadamard gate is often included in the set of such primitive gates.  For example I think we can often easily do a Hadamard gate with one laser pulse or one microwave pulse or one half-mirror, etc.